# ionic 3 annoying always visible scrollbar when accessed on windows

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic3

So, i have built a website using ionic 3 and angular. One particularly annoying thing i have noticed is an always visible scrollbar that appears on all browsers when the website is accessed from windows machine.

This is fine on mac.  I personal understanding was this should be dependent on browser rather the OS. But sadly same browser on different OS shows different behavior.

ultimately, the question is how do i get the same behavior as on mac when the contents are more than my view area. The code for the widget looks like below:

```
 <ion-card class="dashboard-widget-layout dashboard-widget-1-2">
               <ion-card-header class="dashboard-widget-card-header"><ion-label class="dashboard-widget-header">Smart Alerts</ion-label></ion-card-header>
                <ion-card-content style="height: 320px" *ngIf="expanded == false">
                          <ion-scroll style="width:auto" scrollY="true"  class="dashboard-widget-1-2" no-padding>
                              <ion-grid  *ngFor="let opty of optys" style="border-top:1px solid #AFAFAF;margin-right:20px" text-wrap no-padding>
                                  <ion-row text-wrap>
                                  <ion-col (click)="editOpty(opty)" no-padding>
                                          <ion-label class="widget-para-title" style="cursor:pointer">{{opty.name}}</ion-label>
                                           <ion-label class="widget-para-text" style="cursor:pointer">{{opty.account}}</ion-label>
                                  </ion-col>
                                  </ion-row>
                              <ion-row text-wrap>

                              <ion-col>
                                   <ion-label *ngIf="opty.recommendedAction.length > 0" style="margin-top:0px;">{{opty.recommendedAction[0].title}}</ion-label>
                             </ion-col></ion-row>
                              </ion-grid>
                          </ion-scroll>
                </ion-card-content> 

                <ion-row><ion-col></ion-col>
                          <ion-col col-auto text-right no-padding>
                                  <img style="color:white;margin-right:10px" src="{{arrowType}}" (click)="expandWidget()" />
                          </ion-col>
                 </ion-row>
    </ion-card>
```

The view looks like this on mac (all browsers):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/v5eseru0ie304vu/Screenshot%202017-09-28%2017.28.37.png?dl=0

The view looks like this on windows(all browsers):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rbd9lkyeqawow24/SmartAlertHomePageOOWDemoSnap.PNG?dl=0

Comment: I think your forgot to attach the link for windows

Comment: added it just now.

Comment: Great question. I too am looking for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here I am! To solve your question!!

I wasn't going to forget about you bro...

go to **app.scss**
and add

```
.scroll-content{
    overflow-y: auto !important;
}
```

this will solve most of your problems but you may still have some issues with ionic-lab's ios emulator.

If so, go to each html page and add no-bounce and overflow-scroll="false" to ion-content.

the code should look like this

```
<ion-content no-bounce overflow-scroll="false">
</ion-content>
```

lastly for your specific case you may need to add it to ion-card-content as well which would look something like

```
<ion-card-content no-bounce overflow-scroll="false">
</ion-card-content>
```